# updating database with method post Codeigniter

Tags: ajax, post

I want to a homework like this:

There is a list of images in the database, for each image, it has a id, a path, a comment. And I want to realize a text input for each image, to write in comment and update it into database.

In the database, table:images, contains id, path, comment.

Here is the code:

**Image controller:**

```
<?php
class Image extends CI_Controller {
function comment()
{
  $data=array(
    'id'=>$this->input->post('id'),
    'path'=>$this->imageModel->get($this->input->post('id'))->path,
    'comment'=>$this-input->post('comment')
    );
  $result=$this->imageModel->Update($data);

}

}
```

**ImageModel:**

```
<?php
class ImageModel extends CI_Model {
private  $table = 'images';
function ImageModel()
{
 // Call the Model constructor
 parent::__construct();
}

function get($id)
{
$query = $this->db->get_where( $this->table, array('id' => $id) );
return $query->result();
}

function Update($news){
$this->db->where('id',$news->id);
$this->db->update($this->table,$news);
 }
}
```

**Views:**

```
img src="<?php echo base_url();?>/<?php echo $item->path;?>" title ="<?php echo $item->path;?>" rel="<?php echo $item->comment;?>" 
  class ="tips" width=200 height=200></img>

<span><?php echo $item->id;?> :<input type="text" id="<?php echo $item->id;?>"/>
   <input type="submit" id="send<?php echo $item->id;?>"

<script type='text/javascript'>
        window.addEvent("domready",function(){
          $("send<?php echo $item->id;?>").addEvent("click",function(){
            if($("<?php echo $item->id;?>").value==''){
                  alert('Please entre your comment!');
                  return;
                }
            var myRequest = new Request({
                method: 'post',
                url: 'http://localhost/public_html/CodeIgniter/index.php/image/comment',
            onSuccess: function(responseText){
            alert(responseText);
            },
            onFailure: function(){
            alert( 'Erreur!');
            }
        });
            myRequest.send('id='+<?php echo $item->id;?> +'&comment='+$("<?php echo $item->id;?>").value);
    });
    });
    </script>
```

The problem is: when i write something in the text, and click the submit, it always says "Erreur!". I have spent 2 days on it. Can someone help???